# Revolve around a horizontal line in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

I am **very** new to Mathematica. I have version 11, if that makes a difference.

I am trying to take the area formed by the following lines and and revolve it to form a 3D solid.

y = e^-x

Here is my code, in two sections

```
f[x_] := E^-x
g[x_] := 1
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"f[x]", "g[x]", "h[y]"}]
```

Next:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[(1 - f[x]) , {x, 0, 2}, RevolutionAxis -> "X"]
```

Here is the 2D and 3D representations:

[image: 2d image]

[image: 3d image]

The 2D one is correct, but not the 3D. I want to rotate the area about `y=2` (horizontal line) as to form a shape with a hole in the center. I don't know how to set the axis of rotation to anything other than an axis line. I just want `y=2`.

How do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

`RevolutionPlot3D` isn't the right tool for what you want for 2 reasons.  First, you want to rotate a 2D *region* not a line.  Second, you want to rotate around a line that isn't one of the axes. [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html) is the built-in tool for the job.  You can easily set up your region as a boolean region, just think about the conditions that the radius `x^2 + y^2` has to satisfy

```
RegionPlot3D[
 1 < z^2 + y^2 < (2 - Exp[-x])^2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I showed the result from 2 different angles to point out the shortcomings of `RegionPlot3D`.  You could improve this result by using a high value for the `PlotPoints` option, but it isn't great.  That's why you should use Simon Woods's function `contourRegionPlot3D`, defined in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/9490):

```
contourRegionPlot3D[
 1 < z^2 + y^2 < (2 - Exp[-x])^2, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]